# AngularJS display specific String in HTML

Tags: html, angularjs, arrays, string

I'm still in process learning Angular.

For my current project I need to display HTML (eg: `<h1>note1</h1><span>my first note</span><br><h1>note2</h1><span>my second note</span>`) in  my view. I know everyone will suggest to use `ng-bind-html`, but that is not what I want.

What I want is, i want to do checking if string HTML have `note2` then display `my second note`.

In controller I know how to find string `note2` which is use `.match`.

JSON

```
items =
[
    {
        "description": "<h1>note1</h1><span>my first note</span><br><h1>note2</h1><span>my second note</span>"
    }
]
```

In controller find `String` `note2`

```
angular.forEach(items, function(value, key) {
    if (value.description.match("note2")) {
        console.log(value.description);
        // will output HTML <h1>note1</h1><span>my...
    }
    else {
        console.log("string not found");
    }
});
```

I can do till find `String` `note2`, but to display `my second note` I don't have any idea.

Can someone help me with this,
thanks..

Comment: Can you change `items.description` to `value.description`?

Comment: @RameshRajendran yeah already change it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't test this, but maybe you can use split function

```
angular.forEach(items, function(value, key){

    if(items.description.match("note2")){
        console.log(items.description);
        var noteValues = items.description.split("<h1>note2</h1>");
        $scope.mySecondNote = noteValues[1]; // value is <span>my second note</span>
    }else{
        console.log("string not found");
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

**Plunker DEMO** [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/d4JONJJtSaYwVpyd66Px?p=preview)

Comment: @RameshRajendran OP wants to get ONLY the `my second note` text. This code get exactly like what OP wants. See DEMO here [link](https://plnkr.co/edit/d4JONJJtSaYwVpyd66Px?p=preview)

Comment: @rachmatsasongko thanks mate! your answer is clean (y)

Answer (score 1):

It should be `value.description.`, because `items` is an array

```
 angular.forEach(items, function(value, key) {
      if (value.description.match("note2")) {
}
```

**DEMO**

```js
var app = angular.module('todoApp', []);

app.controller("dobController", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
    items = [{
      "description": "<h1>note1</h1><span>my first note</span><br><h1>note2</h1><span>my second note</span>"
    }];
    angular.forEach(items, function(value, key) {
      if (value.description.match("note2")) {
        console.log(value.description);
        // will output HTML <h1>note1</h1><span>my...
      } else {
        console.log("string not found");
      }
    });
  }
]);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="todoApp">

<head>
  <title>To Do List</title>
  <link href="skeleton.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="MainViewController.js"></script>
</head>


<body ng-controller="dobController">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Sajeetharan. I dont want to output all `HTML`. I want to get text `my second note`. What do you do is displaying all HTML text

Comment: Plus, If you noticed from my point, I want to display `my second note` if checking in controller found `note2`. Have any idea to get this `my second note` text ?

Comment: Those people up vote for this answer is not understanding my question

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
if (items[0].description.match("note2")) {
    console.log(items[0].description);
    // will output HTML <h1>note1</h1><span>my...
}
else {
    console.log("string not found");
}
```

Comment: ask to OP for, Why OP using loop?

Comment: cuz my real data was loop. That is why I'm giving example `JASON` in loop